# need custom LibraryPicker with initial image on custom cameraOverlay UIImagePickerController iOS8

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm wondering how I can add the default Library picker button that can be found on an iPhone's default Camera app(can also be accessed via dashboard). The button looks like this, though this is an app custom implementation:

[image]

So I know that it can be done, but how? It's the library image picker that you can see the taxi car in. I'm using a completely customized UIImagePickerController through the use of the imagePickerController's property `customOverlay` view and I need to add this very same button to my overlayView. If someone could guide me towards a solution that'd be of great help, thanks!

I can imagine using `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` for the button and simply setting the button's `imageView` property to the first picture in the camera roll, but how would I go about doing this?

**Also**, is this somehow controllable by iOS default `UIImagePickerController`